# Remote command to bash variable followed by if statement, but output is read incorrectly?

Tags: bash

I don't know if this is even possible, but I am running a command to check if there are servers on a node. This is used as a safety precaution so the script I am writing does not kickstart hardware nodes which are actually in use. However I am not getting the desired result.

I am using the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
checkempty=$(ssh root@$HWNODEIP "vzlist -o veid")

if [ "$checkempty" == "Container(s) not found" ]; then
  echo "Hardware node is empty! Proceeding with kickstart"
  else
  echo "Found VPS? Please investigate. Quitting kickstart"
fi
```

#### Result when running the command

```
Container(s) not found
Found VPS? Please investigate. Quitting kickstart
```

Obivously this is incorrect. There are no servers on the selected hardware node.

#### Expected result when running the command

```
Container(s) not found
Hardware node is empty! Proceeding with kickstart
```

What I am doing wrong? I tried escaping those parenthesis symbols. I also tried using backticks. But so far no luck. I even tried using a wildcard in combination with "not found", but also no go.

Probably it's something small I am overlooking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In bash, `VAR=$( cmd )` assigns the standard output (STDOUT) of `cmd` to `VAR`. It is possible that `vzlist` prints its error on `STDERR`, and that `STDOUT` is empty.

Try `checkempty=$(ssh root@$HWNODEIP "vzlist -o veid" 2>&1)` instead. `2>&1` redirects STDERR into STDOUT.

Comment: thank you! I never knew this! I really thought I was doing something wrong... So thank you for your answer and explanation. Working now as expected!